# CEF3 with WINAPI

Tags: winapi, window, chromium-embedded

I don't know if the subject of this topic makes sense.
I've een trying some work around with CEF3. 
I just started using C++ and I'm having a hard time. Sorry about that.

The initial target is to make the popup window full-screen as described in this topic:  http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=11706

I also think that this one is a better approach: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10772. However, there are no sufficient explanations. 
What do you think needs to be added in the snippet below in order for the browser to run in a window based from WINAPI.

```
#include <windows.h>
// Source taken here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html

const char g_szClassName[] = "MultiscreenProject";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Full-screen mode
    RECT desktop;

    // Get a handle to the desktop window
    const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();

    // Get the size of screen to the variable desktop
    GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);

    // The top left corner will have coordinates (0,0)
    // and the bottom right corner will have coordinates
    // (horizontal, vertical)
    int horizontal = desktop.right;
    int vertical = desktop.bottom;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if( !RegisterClassEx(&wc) ) {
        MessageBox( NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK );
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        g_szClassName,
        "Multiscreen Project",
        WS_POPUP,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, horizontal, vertical,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );

    if( hwnd == NULL ){
        MessageBox( NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK );
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while( GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 ) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've read this question several times, but I still don't understand what the problem is. Do you want an explanation of how the code you posted works? Or you do want someone to help you *fix* the code? If the latter, what *specifically* is wrong with the code? What is it doing, and what do you *want* it to do instead?

Comment: I'm asking for suggestions on how to bind CEF3 with WINAPI. In such a way that the Chromium browser would run on a window from a WINAPI if it's possible.

Comment: Have you checked out the CefClient/CefSimple projects? Maybe I have misunderstood, but don't they run Cef from a native Win32 app using WINAPI?

Comment: @CodyGray Can I have your permission to copy-paste this as a sort of 'standard operating procedure' all over SO? :)

Comment: @Sharadh Sure. You might also like [this extension](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Pure gold! Many thanks! Now, let me stop polluting the comments here!

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you need to do this:

1. create your implementation of [CefApp](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefApp.html) and [CefMainArgs](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefMainArgs.html)
2. create [CefSettings](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefSettings.html)
3. init CEF: [CefInitialize()](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/%28_globals%29.html#CefInitialize%28constCefMainArgs&,constCefSettings&,CefRefPtr%3CCefApp%3E%29)
4. create window by WinAPI
5. create your implementation of [CefClient](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefClient.html)
6. create [CefWindowInfo](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefWindowInfo.html) with HWND of your window
7. call [CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser()](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefBrowserHost.html#CreateBrowser%28constCefWindowInfo&,CefRefPtr%3CCefClient%3E,constCefString&,constCefBrowserSettings&,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequestContext%3E%29) <-- binding CEF to window
8. show your window

Don't forget to integrate CEF messages' loop into WndProc of your app: [Message_Loop_Integration](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-message-loop-integration)